# Show all children of a specific taxonomy term using Views exposed filters

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a Views exposed filter that checks nodes with specific terms. I can't seem to find an option to display all children of a term if the parent term is selected.

For example, I will outline a vocabulary:

```
Parent 1
 - Child 1
 - Child 2
 - Child 3
   - Another child
Parent 2
 - Child again
```

If I select "Parent 1" as part of my filtering process, it will display any nodes tagged with that Term. However I'd like it to display all children as well as just the term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contextual filters (in the Advanced section) has a parent filter.

Also if you add a Relationship to parent you can make use of that within normal filters.

Comment: Is there any link which gives more detail with example?

Comment: maybe this? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86367/contextual-filter-in-taxonomy-drupal-7/86374#86374

Answer (score 0):

You could change the way you use your taxonomy's to always include the parent.

For example try using the cck content taxonomy tree widget, then add a little custom js so any time a child is checked the parent it also automatically checked.